After Kant called God a "moral ideal", did any philosopher develop a theory of how God's World could possibly work?
Did any philosopher since Kant, go beyond simply believing in God, and actually developing a concept/theory of how our reality created by God can exist/develop/end?

"According to Immanuel Kant, God is best understood as a "moral ideal"
or "the ideal of pure reason," essentially a concept that represents
the ultimate source of morality and serves as a necessary postulate
for ethical behavior, rather than a being with anthropomorphic
qualities that can be known through empirical observation; meaning, we
can't directly perceive God, but we can access the idea of God through
our reason and moral imperative to act ethically."
https://revistapublicando.org/revista/index.php/crv/article/download/1332/pdf_970/5163#:~:text=God%20in%20Kant's%20critical%20philosophy,%22%20or%20%22transcendental%20example%22.

Georg Wilhelm Friedrich Hegel - developed understanding of God's "Absolute Idea" guiding the history of human society.
Did anybody else?

Developing theories is trivial. Developing convincing theories is a lot harder. Developing testable theories, or even theories that allow further exploration when taken as hypothesis, it harder again. The question I would ask would be weather anybody developed a theory that other philosophers considered worth further exploring.

I don't think Kant's idea is consistent with "reality created by God". In his philosophy, God isn't a being that creates anything. It's just a name we give for the source of morality.

If by "God's world" you mean a world of Kantian God then even Hegel's Absolute Idea is hardly Kantian, Fichte's "moral lawgiver" is probably closer. And neo-Kantians largely abandoned Kant's quasi-theological constructions. But if you just mean generic monotheistic God as the source of morality then theistic philosophers wrote volumes on how his world was created, develops and will end before, during and after Kant, see SEP, Religion and Morality in Western Philosophy.

Michael Dummett, well-known for his study of Frege and his attempt to apply intuitionist metamathematical views to philosophical semantics, was a practicing catholic since his adolescence. In Thought and Reality (based on lectures he gave in 1996) he wrote a rather strange last chapter about "God and the World". Some quotes:

The concept of the world as a whole is correlative to that of God, as standing over against the world. If that contrast is removed, no room remains for distinguishing the world as it is in itself from the world as we experience it and find it to be.

He seems to think it is impossible to conceive of the world "as it is in itself":

We can make no clear sense of there being a world that is not apprehended by any mind. (...) Since it makes no sense to speak of a world, or the world, independently of how it is apprehended, this one world must be the world as it is apprehended by some mind, yet not in any particular way,

This, according to him, is the way God apprehends things:

How things are in themselves consists in the way that God apprehends them.


Since God's knowledge of how things are constitutes their being as they are, He is rightly called Creator; this applies as much to His knowledge of the propositions we can frame and to whose truth we can attain as to His knowledge of those framed and recognized as true by other inhabitants of the universe, but lying beyond our grasp. It is only in virtue of God's constituting the truth of all these propositions by His knowledge of them that we can regard all sentient creatures as dwellers in the same world.

I don't really know what to make of these kind of quasi-Kantian statements which to me border on the nonsensical. It reminded me of Freud's famous saying that no one can imagine their own death, presumably because imagining this still presupposes someone who is imagining. Bertrand Russell's response to that was: "I have no problem imagining my own death. My body will lie in a casket, rotting away in the earth, and I will no longer be there."

I can see the pattern of confused obfuscation. But I don't fully understand why. For any living person, there is a simple question with a binary choice: This World is a random chaos, or it is not? And if you think it is not, then there is a wide plain open to discuss what influence/role 'intelligent design' plays in our reality.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance You may be aware that Gödel's posthumous work also contains an ontological proof of God's existence. (Excellent summary here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZBg_cHg4NA1l_t5CodYGKgUvkhmXpu0K9rko1ysgtFs/edit?tab=t.0) The main weakness in the argument -- admitted by G afaik -- is that we should first prove that it is possible that God exists. Another way, imo, of stating this is that we should first prove that the concept of necessary existence makes sense. To me it doesn't -- somehow it's "evident" to me that all actual existence is contingent.

I don't understand this part. All it takes is to make an assumption that metaphysics plays a role in our reality. The same way as most philosophers made an assumption that our reality is not a fruit of our inflamed consciousness.

No answer is an answer.
It confirms my longstanding suspicions. Attempts to try to build a non-physical model of our reality became a sort of a taboo in modern philosophy and was relegated solely to religious scholars.
The Simulation Hypothesis is kind of an exception.
But this is very unfortunate. There are huge and glaring gaps (unsolved questions) in Cosmology, Quantum mechanics, Biology, Sociology, ... .
The normal empirical science cannot tackle the most fundamental questions about our reality, and philosophy could help to fill the void.
